# How to analyze the below query in parts

Tags: sql

How to analyze the below query in parts

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
           FROM Employee Emp2
           WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary
           )
```

Please explain through example.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: sounds like a work order to me..please try something . simplest idea is  time it

Comment: @GordonLinoff:I am confused with how where condition evaluate with the subqurery

Comment: My analysis: whoever wrote the query doesn't understand what `distinct` does. Because distinct is not a function and the the expression `distinct(emp2.salary)` gives me the impression the author thinks just that and assumes `distinct` would only work on the columns "passed" to the "function"

Comment: @avisingh05 . . . This is called a correlated subquery.  A fine place to start is Wikipedia:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This will give employee records with nth highest salary.
This is a correlated sub-query. The inner query uses a value from the outer query (in this case the Emp1 table) in it’s WHERE clause.

Suppose there are below values of sal:

```
100
300
500
200
```

and you want to find 2nd highest sal then for 300 (salary) in outer query the inner query will return 1 as count for Emp2.sal>Emp1.sal i.e. for 500 (N-1 , 2-1=1)